# Slow update of the Draft.js / react-draft-wysiwyg DOM when content change

Tags: javascript, redux-saga, draftjs, react-boilerplate, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm using react-draft-wysiwyg wrapper for Draft.js. 
On the page I have multiple instances of the Editor component. 
I have problem with slowly/laggy update of the Editor UI (`onChange` event handler).
Maybe this is some hint Im getting a lot of warning in the console `[Violation] 'input' handler took <N>msA`.

[image: Screenshot from 2019-03-29 22-02-43]

My setup is:

- react-boilerplate
- react-draft-wysiwyg
- redux
- redux-saga
- reselect

Im dispatching action to handle editor state change its handled by redux-saga.
Saga will check if new content and update the store.

```
export function* handleOnEditorStateChange({ editorState, nameSpace }) {
  const actualEditorState = yield select(selectAllEditorsContent());
  const editorIndexToUpdate = actualEditorState.findIndex(
    editors => editors.name === nameSpace,
  );
  const currentContent = actualEditorState[
    editorIndexToUpdate
  ].state.getCurrentContent();
  const newContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();

  const hasEditorNewContent = newContent !== currentContent;

  if (hasEditorNewContent) {
    const updatedEditorState = [...actualEditorState];
    updatedEditorState[editorIndexToUpdate].state = editorState;

    yield put(storeEditorStateAction(updatedEditorState));
  }
}
```

My redux state looks like that:

```js
...
editors: [
    {
      name: 'editor1',
      label: 'Editor 1',
      state: {... _immutable - draftjs }
    },
    {
      name: 'editor2',
      label: 'Editor 2',
      state: {... _immutable - draftjs }
    },
]
...
```

Reducer:

```
...
    case STORE_EDITOR_STATE: {
      const { content } = action;
      return state.set('editors', content);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. At least some walk around. 
I have changed the way I'm handling action in my action watcher saga. 
Instead of `takaLates` effect I changed to `throttle` with a small delay. And it's much much better.